# Excel - if one cell equals Bilbo Baggins, check other table for Bilbo Baggins and then give me the value in a cell 3 columns along

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table, it's basically a reporting table.  It's a subset of another table.

I want to search the name in my subset, then find it in the main table and find the value for a certain thing.

## Subset

| Name | Attendance |
| --- | --- |
| Eoin | **Unknown** |
| Peter | **Unknown** |

## Main dataset

| Name | Age | Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eoin | 21 | 4 |
| Paul | 42 | 12 |
| Mary | 13 | 1 |
| Peter | 99 | 0 |

What I want to do is to get the attendance in the main dataset and enter it into my subset (marked unknown in my example).

I have done a VLookup but it's returning 1 which is not the right value.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Traffic Lights'!D3:Q35,5,FALSE)
```

- A2 is the name in the subset.
- Traffic Lights D3:D3 is the data in
  another sheet in the same workbook.
- 5 is the column number in the other worksheet.
- FALSE I didn't really know what to use.  But the other worksheet is not sorted in any way.  The first column is the names of the people.

Comment: `5` is not the column number but the **RELATIVE** column number which means it would be retuning the data that in column `H` as it is the fifth column in the range: `D3:Q35`.  And it is looking for the Match in column `D`

Comment: Oohhhh I see.  Ledge!  Thanks.  Please can you put this as the answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Is there a way I can fill across and have the column increment?

Comment: @Eoin If you want to do that I’d try a different approach.  Instead of using  a VLOOKUP function and then filling multiple VLOOKUPs across, you can use INDEX(MATCH()).  Also, this all gets WAY easier with Excel O365, if you have that version.  Which version are you using?

Comment: Yes I'm using O365

Comment: O365 version would be `=XLOOKUP(A2,$D$3:$D$21,$F$3:$F$21,"Not Found")` - look for A2 value in D3:D21 and return the value from F3:F21.  If nothing found return "Not Found".  Can be dragged across with relative referencing.